# Suse equivalent of Solaris' ls -V

Tags: solaris, nfs, acl, suse

using NFS in solaris result in (sort of) acl creation.

by "sort of" I mean a peculiar command will reveal acl existence

```
Solaris # mkdir T2
Solaris # getfacl T2

# file: T2
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::r-x              #effective:r-x
mask:rwx
other:r-x
Solaris # ls -V
total 3
drwxr-xr-x+  2 root     root           2 Mar  8 08:35 T2
           group:foobar:rwxp-DaARWcCos:fd-----:allow
            group:admin:rwxp-DaARWcCos:fd-----:allow
                 owner@:rwxp-DaARWcCos:-------:allow
                 group@:r-x---a-R-c--s:-------:allow
              everyone@:r-x---a-R-c--s:-------:allow
```

as you can see, `getfacl` reveal nothing, but `ls -V` show extended right.

I have check that being member of `foobar` allow me to create dir and files.

- with extended right / ACL (e.g. a + in ls -l ) on solaris
- without extended right  / ACL  on suse (11.4)

The current dir is based on a zfs nfs exported filesystem.

now the questions:

- where are those ACL set ?
- how to set them in suse environment ?

Comment: Have you looked at the official SUSE docs? https://www.suse.com/documentation/sles10/book_sle_reference/data/cha_acls.html

Answer (score 4):

As per `man ls` in solaris

> -V
>
> The same as -l, except that compact ACL  information  is displayed after the -l output.
>
> The -V option is only applicable to  file  systems  that support NFSv4 ACLs, such as the Solaris ZFS file system.

This lead us to [nfsv4 acl](https://www.suse.com/documentation/sles-12/stor_admin/data/cha_nfs4_acls.html%20nfsv4%20acl) on suse.

Listing access right is done by `nfs4-getfacl` (as per online documentation) or `nfs4_getfacl` (actual file installed from nfs4-acl-tools package).

extract from man nfs4_getacl

```
   The output format for an NFSv4 file ACL, e.g., is:

          A::OWNER@:rwatTnNcCy
          A::alice@nfsdomain.org:rxtncy
          A::bob@nfsdomain.org:rwadtTnNcCy
          A:g:GROUP@:rtncy
          D:g:GROUP@:waxTC
          A::EVERYONE@:rtncy
          D::EVERYONE@:waxTC
```

This differ from solaris version.

It is unclear if solaris nfs4 acl can be translated to suse nfs4 acl.

Comment: `nfs4_getfacl` does accurately present the ACL as defined in ZFS.  At least with Ubuntu 16.04 nfs client, Solaris 11.3 NFS server, and the mount being NFS v4.

Comment: I can't test it right now. Ultimatly I will drop solaris, so should I use ZFS +NFSv4+NFS4 ACL or (xfs or ext4)+NFSv3+Posix ACL ?

Comment: If you can meet your needs with POSIX permission sets, then that's certainly an option.  If you need more fine-grained permissions, then keep using NFS v4 with v4 style ACLs.   I've put some examples below.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how the appear on Solaris w/ZFS, Linux w/ NFSv4, and Linux w/ NFSv3:

Solaris 11.3 ZFS Filesystem:

```
bash-[509]$ ls -Vd /ssd/TIVO
drwxrwxr-x+ 12 tim      users         15 Feb 23 17:34 /ssd/TIVO/
               user:tim:rwxpdDaARWcCos:fd-----:allow
                 owner@:rwxp-DaARWcCos:-------:allow
                 group@:rwxp-DaARWc--s:-------:allow
              everyone@:r-x---a-R-c--s:-------:allow
```

Linux client with NFS v4 mount of Solaris 11.3 ZFS/NFS filesystem:

```
bash:~$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

bash:~$ mount | grep TIVO
tank:/ssd/TIVO on /ssd/TIVO type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.0,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,port=0,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=192.168.0.100,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.2.1)

bash:~$ nfs4_getfacl /ssd/TIVO
A:fd:tim@tank:rwaDdxtTnNcCoy
A::OWNER@:rwaDxtTnNcCoy
A:g:GROUP@:rwaDxtTnNcy
A::EVERYONE@:rxtncy
```

Linux client with NFS v3 mount of Solaris 11.3 ZFS/NFS filesystem:

```
bash:/ssd# lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

bash:/ssd# mount | grep TIVO
tank:/ssd/TIVO on /ssd/TIVO type nfs (rw,relatime,vers=3,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=192.168.2.1,mountvers=3,mountport=59133,mountproto=tcp,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.2.1)

bash:/ssd# getfacl /ssd/TIVO
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: ssd/TIVO
# owner: tim
# group: users
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::r-x
```